# Access cloud service and blob storage simultaneously

Tags: azure, cdn

I went over this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff919703.aspx) and I was able to setup a `CDN` successfully.

The problem is that the portal allows me to either create a `CDN` for the `blob storage` or for the `cloud service`.  It does not allow me to create one `CDN` for each service.

I am not sure if this is because the `blob storage` is linked as resource to the `cloud service` or if there are problems with the `Azure` portal.

What would be the recommended way to serve dynamic content from a `cloud service` and static content form `blob storage` for the same web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create the same CDN endpoint for both blob and cloud service, but what is your scenario where you need to do this?  Create 2 CDN endpoints, one pointing to blob and the other to your cloud service.

Assuming your domain name is myapp.com you could have something like this:

1. CNAME www.myapp.com -> CDN endpoint for cloud service
2. CNAME content.myapp.com -> CDN endpoint for blob storage
3. Your cloud service would return content with the href's pointing to content.myapp.com.

Comment: Thanks kwill. That is what I supposed at the begging; that I need two endpoints. The problem is that the portal does not allow me to create two. If I create one for the cloud service when I go back to create the second endpoint, the blob service is not displayed and vice-verse. Maybe an issue with the portal? I think Azure is upgrading their CDN service.

Comment: Is your storage name and cloud service name the same thing?  i.e. myapp.cloudapp.net and myapp.blob.core.windows.net?  If yes, then this is a known issue and will be getting resolved within the next few days.  You can work around it for now by renaming one of them.

Comment: That is good to know. Yes, both services have the same name. Thanks for the information. I can wait some days so I avoid renaming the service.

Comment: In case this helps anyone... I am now able to select the blob storage and the cloud service creating two end points. As kwill mentioned, this is (was) a bug in Azure.